# p_validate_txn - unable to find MBL customer REF id

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have added a customer to QuickBooks desktop using Intuit Anywhere. When I try and sync a Sales Receipt, I get this error:

p_validate_txn - unable to find MBL customer REF id = [number] idDomain = QB

My code for returning a customer id:

```
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            List<Customer> customersList = new List<Customer>();
            string theName = GetCustId(ord);

            CustomerQuery query = new CustomerQuery();

            if (_qboSettings.CustomerID != "SingleName")
            {
                query.FirstLastName = ord.BillingAddress.FirstName + " " + ord.BillingAddress.LastName.Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                query.FirstLastName = theName.Trim();
            }
            customersList = query.ExecuteQuery<Customer>(dataServices.ServiceContext).ToList();


            //for customers that do not exist, return the ID and add them
            if (customersList.Count() == 0)
            {
                return BuildCustomerAddRq(ord).Id.Value;
            }

            return customersList.FirstOrDefault().Id.Value;
```

When I ran a customer query, here was the response:

http://pastebin.com/rtyA8KKL

It appears I am incorrectly querying my customers? When I run the Intuit Sync Manager, I see no new customers in my QuickBooks Desktop. Is this supposed to happen?

Here is the Rest Response when creating the Sales Receipt:

http://pastebin.com/QE5YwjVB

This issue happens with customers that already exist. I created John Smith in my QB and the item for the order. I ran the sync manager. I still get this error, even with an existing customer.

Comment: Please post the request/response XML from the SalesReceipt Create call that is throwing that error (http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0200_DevKits/0100_IPP_.NET_DevKit/0600_Logging).

Comment: OK, see my new code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the sales receipt, could you try passing the Customer id and customer name in the request ?

Comment: Thanks. I did Customer Name instead and that error has been resolved.